# no result when http authentification via php curl

Tags: php, html, apache, curl, basic-authentication

I have a web server secured by http. I want to log in to this server1 via another one. When i use this url : http://username:password@server1. It works.

Now i want to execute this url from another webpage in server2. I'm using Curl.

```
<?php
$username='username';
$password='password';
$URL='http://server1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result ;
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

This is not working for me. I have just the pop-up to log with http. What's wrong in my php page ?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$username                ='username';
$password                ='password';
$yourEfforts             = array();
$yourEfforts['username']=$username; //stored in yourEfforts array.
$yourEfforts['password']=$password; //stored in yourEfforts array.
$URL='http://server1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $yourEfforts);//Your username and password
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));//debug curl exec output
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));//debug curl info
var_dump(curl_error($ch));//debug curl error
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result ;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I got a page with "Unauthorized".

Comment: Does it returns 401 Unauthorized ?

Comment: yes with your version it returns the "401 Unauthorized". and with the previous one it got "301 Moved Permanently - The document has moved here."

Comment: // check for errors before close
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false)
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

Comment: I always get the "401 Unauthorized". but when i try with a browser using the classical method with username and password via the URL it works.

Comment: the classical method ??

Comment: i want to say by that using directly the url " username:password@ip

Comment: I didn't found a solution. I need to tape the url in a browser to go through the http authentification :(